# Extracting String, number group, next string, next number group

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie to Regex and I am struggling to find a solution to my problem. I have a file with multiple entries. Here is an example:

1)Hello my is blah blah blah. Blah blah Building 5677 - Door 98 blah blah blah.

2)Hi, the name of my dog is blah blah Building 36767 & Door 898900 blah blah blah.

3)Hey now, blah blah Building 345 DR 898. Blah Blah blag Building 333 - Door 89797 blah.

I need to extract each instance of Building number and Door number from each line. The only pattern that is constant throughout each entry is:

1) the word "Building" is always present.

2) "Building" is always followed by a group of integers...the letter "D | d"...and a second group of integers (followed by a non-integer).

All I want is to pull is Building number and Door number and print to console, but I am having trouble translating this into a regex pattern. I am using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Building.+?(\d+).+?[Dd].+?(\d+)
```

Your numbers will be in groups 1 and 2.

```
Building //start by matching "Building"
.+?      //then skip over the least number of characters that allows the match
(\d+)    //then read as many digits as possible and put them in group one
.+?      //then skip over the least number of characters that allows the match
[Dd]     //then match an upper- or lower-case 'D' 
.+?      //then skip over the least number of characters that allows the match
(\d+)    //then read as many digits as possible and put them in group two
```

So in Java:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Building.+?(\\d+).+?[Dd].+?(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = 
pat.matcher("Hello my is blah blah blah. Blah blah Building 5677 - Door 98 blah blah blah. ");
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
   System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

### Edit

To extract more than one set of numbers from one input, as in your third example, you can use

```
while (matcher.find()) {
```

Instead of using `if` to find it just once.

Comment: Dude! For you to pull that out in that short of time...you deserve the Nobel Prize. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: Hi Mark, your solution was an immense help to me...much appreciated. However, I've came across another issue (but in the same context). I am new to this forum, so should I post another question, or leave the question as a comment? Thank you!!!

Comment: @John: If it's unrelated, post a new question.  If it's an issue you're having implementing a solution to the same problem, you can either edit your question or post a new one and link back to this.  By editing an old question there's a good chance it won't get noticed much.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think it qualifies as a new question...I will post as such. Thanks again.

Comment: @John: no problem.  If you consider this question answered, you can mark it as such by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that most helped you.  That'll let people know that this question is "closed" (i.e. answered).

Comment: Mark, I'm sorry to bother you again. Before I close this one, I just wanted to ask you: can you give me a regex pattern for something like this: 'Building Dr 4647 8989'. I am looking to pull both '4647' and '8989' consecutively (almost exactly the same as the one you helped me with). Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Mark, never mind, I figured it out (thx to your example)...just in case your curious, I used: Building[ ]+?[Dd].+?(\\d+).+?(\\d+). thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Regex to find Building numbers -

```
(?<=Building\\s)[0-9]+
```

Similarly for Door numbers -

```
(?<=Door\\s)[0-9]+
```

To put it together -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputStr = "Hello my is blah blah blah. Blah blah Building 5677 - Door 98 blah blah blah";

    Pattern patternBuilding = Pattern.compile("(?<=Building\\s)[0-9]+");
    Pattern patternDoor = Pattern.compile("(?<=Door\\s)[0-9]+");
    Matcher matcherBuilding = patternBuilding.matcher(inputStr);
    Matcher matcherDoor = patternDoor.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcherBuilding.find())
        System.out.println("Building number is " + matcherBuilding.group());
    if (matcherDoor.find())
        System.out.println("Door number is " + matcherDoor.group());
}
```

Comment: Won't work - make sure you read the WHOLE question, as you apparently missed the part about 'Door' not always being like that.

Comment: Those lookahead patterns (?=pattern) don't work on most interpreters for some reason (I think, or, I'm too dumb). It appears like they only work if the lookahead part is not at the beginning of the whole expression.

Comment: @josh - Ah! Mark's answer below makes more sense. @Efrain- the patterns work with Java (6)